# NSFetchedResultsController: doc clarification needed

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I need some clarifications from the Apple documentation

> The fetch request must have at least one sort descriptor. If the
>   controller generates sections, the first sort descriptor in the array
>   is used to group the objects into sections; its key must either be the
>   same as sectionNameKeyPath **or the relative ordering using its key must
>   match that using sectionNameKeyPath**.

I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with sections in the following way

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:mainContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"paymentDate"
                                               cacheName:nil];
```

As I understood from the doc, the `NSFetchRequest` I pass in the `NSFetchedResultsController` must at least a sort descriptors. But since I use sections, the sort descriptor must be like the following:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"paymentDate" ascending:YES],
        [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"paymentCode" ascending:YES],
        nil]];
```

If I use sort descriptors like

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"paymentCode" ascending:YES],
        nil]];
```

I receive an error like the following

> NSFetchedResultsController ERROR: The fetched object at index X has an
>   out of order section name Y. Objects must be sorted by section name'

In my case, using `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"paymentDate" ascending:YES]`, it allows me to overcome the problem. Maybe I'm only lucky ;).

But, what does it mean **or the relative ordering using its key must match that using sectionNameKeyPath**? Could you provide me an explanation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sections, then the FRC needs to know how to sort the array of data so that it can group all the results by section.  Thus, whatever you specify as the first sort descriptor in the fetch request, must match how your sections are to be grouped so that the FRC can do it properly.

You don't have to specify they exact field, but the sort order should be the same.

For example, if your first sort descriptor would group the array by section, even though it did not reference the section, then it would be fine.  In most cases, you should explicitly specify your section attribute to remove any possibility for confusion on the part of the FRC -- or it will throw an exception.

**EDIT**

For example, let's say you have two sort descriptors: `sd1` and `sd2`.  `sd1` uses the same key as provided to the FRC in `sectionNameKeyPath`.  `sd2` uses a different key.

When you sort the entire array, if they both produce a final array that groups the entities in the same sections, then you can use either `sd1` or `sd2` as the first sort descriptor.

Basically, they FRC will group the entities into sections based on the `sectionNameKeyPath`  so it can determine how many sections there are, and how many rows are in each section.  Thus, the array it gets as input must be sorted into similar groupings, relative to the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

As it trolls through the array, it looks at the `sectionNameKeyPath` and expects to see a specific number of entries with the same `sectionNameKeyPath`.  Thus, the array must be sorted to keep all the sections together.

If you can accomplish that without specifying the same key as the first sort descriptor, then everything will work fine.  If not, then you should use the same section key as the first sort descriptor.

Comment: +1 for your reply. Could you specify what do you mean with "You don't have to specify they exact field, but the sort order should be the same."? A little sample could be useful ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jody. You have a great knowledge about Core Data. Cheers.